# remove special characters to get string in python list

Tags: python

I have the following code which gives me list as shown below

```
listP= methodcall()
print(listP)
```

> Output [('abcd',), ('efgh',)

How do I remove bracket,comma and single quotes?

I need below output:-

```
listP=['abcd','efgh']
```

Comment: i can see the type of `listP` is `Output`, but how to access the values inside this `Output` class instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
listp = [('abcd',), ('efgh',)]
listp = [l[0] for l in listp]
print(listp)
```

Take only first element from the tuples in the original list using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```py
newlist = []
list1 = [('abcd',), ('efgh',)]
for elements in list1:
  newlist.append(elements[0])

print(newlist)
```